# How to find an element in a table that has an ID but I need to look for it by name?

Tags: sql, union

I am trying to solve this question but how can I get the information about the lecturer if I assume that I don't know the `StaffID`?

I tried to solve the question with two approaches, one assuming that I don't know the `StaffID`, and the other assuming that I do know the `StaffID`.

Here is the question: List detail registration records for all courses taught by lecturer Musa.

For example, if we know the `StaffID`:

```
SELECT StaffID, Reg.NO, MatricNO, Code, Kulliyyah, Venue, Time, Day
FROM registration
WHERE StaffID = 401
```

Alternatively, suppose that we don’t know about the `StaffID`:

```
SELECT StaffID, Lecturer
FROM Lecturer
WHERE Lecturer = Musa 
UNION 
            SELECT StaffID
 FROM registration
WHERE registration .StuffID = Lecturer. StaffID
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is JOIN (not Union).

It seems odd that Lecturer is both a table name and a column name. Also typo StuffID

Aliases have been added, as R and L, to shorted the qualification.
Quotes have been added around the lecturer's name.

```
SELECT R.StaffID, Reg.NO, MatricNO, Code, Kulliyyah, Venue, Time, Day 
FROM registration as R
LEFT JOIN Lecturer as L
ON R.StaffID = L.StaffID
Where L.Lecturer = 'Musa'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic `JOIN` query:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM registration r JOIN
     Lecturer L
     ON r.StaffID = l.StaffID
WHERE l.Lecturer = 'Musa';
```